# integral of indicator $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{2a(x-y)}1_{|x-y|<t-s} dx $

Tags: integration, functions

How can I solve this equation $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{2a(x-y)}1_{|x-y|<t-s} dx $

Is that correct
$=\int_0^{t-s} e^{2a(x-y)} dx$

let $z=x-y$

$=\int_{-y}^{t-s-y} e^{2az} dz$

Does not look correct.

Comment: $|x-y|<t-s$ if $x<t-s+y$ OR $x>-t+s+y$, therefore you should solve two integrals.

Answer (score 0):

If $t<s$ then the integral is trivially zero. Let us assume from now on that $t\geq s$. Then

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\!dx~ e^{2a(x-y)}~1_{|x-y|<t-s} 
~\stackrel{z=x-y}{=}~\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dz~ e^{2az}~1_{|z|<t-s}~=~\int_{s-t}^{t-s}dz~ e^{2az}$$
$$~=~\left\{\begin{array}{ccc}\left[ \frac{e^{2az}}{2a}\right]_{z=s-t}^{z=t-s}
&=&\frac{1}{a}\sinh(2a(t-s))&\text{for}& a\neq 0,\\\\ 
\left[ z\right]_{z=s-t}^{z=t-s}&=&2(t-s)&\text{for}& a= 0.\end{array}\right.$$